# Texture Painting not working with a blank image

Tags: texturing, transparency, texture-painting

I'm trying to texture a model using a blank image as base, with transparency. However, no changes are being shown, which is driving me insane. Using not-blank textures works fine, so what am I missing?

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What blend type do you have on the brush?

Comment: `Add`, only "Alpha" enabled (disabling isn't fixing it though).

Comment: Your image is entirely transparent, that probably has something to do with it

Comment: The blank texture has alpha, and if you use Add Blend type it will not do anything to the texture.

Comment: True, turning it to `Mix` fixed it, thanks!

Comment: @Denis You writing that as an answer? I think it solved the issue

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise I'm not near my computer at the moment, it's fine if someone else writes it s an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is the blend mode you're using. When you paint with the add blend mode, it doesn't effect the alpha channel at all. So if you paint on transparency, it's still transparent. When you paint on a part that partly transparent, it only effects the color, and the opacity stays the same.

The solution is to instead use the mix blend mode. Instead of adding to the values of the image like the add blend mode does, this mixes the two values.